# known bug? windows terminal + WSL gets extremely slow after computer sleeps

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, windows-terminal

I am unsure if this is a known bug or not, but when I have windows terminal open + WSL and my computer goes to sleep, often times when I log back in I find using it to be extremely slow, as well as any applications running from it (e.g. vscode). When this happens `Vmmem` is usually chewing up a ton of memory and I cannot restart it. I end up having to reboot my computer for it to run normally again. This feels like some sort of memory leak. Is this a known bug? And if not, is there a way to mitigate this?

Comment: There is https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9429, but that hasn't been triaged yet. That might be a lead. Otherwise, I'd chime in over on that thread/repo. They might be able to get diagnostics from you to help ID the issue you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question with my "solution".
I think this is most likely a bug of some kind.
My working solution is to close the WSL terminal and all WSL applications, then open PowerShell and run `wsl --shutdown`.
After this my computer gets all around much faster and I can boot a new instance of WSL before the heatdeath of the universe.

Comment: But this happens very often for me. This solution works but the same happens very often. Any other solutions ?

Comment: @SudarshanAnbazhagan I would like to know another answer as well since this happens often for me too, I'm setting this answer as unaccepted for now

Comment: have also been dealing with this for over a year now. Sleep seems to induce bloating on vmmem process and wsl / docker slows to a halt. I have a sneaking suspicion it could be one of the 5 corp apps on my laptop for security (since it doesn't happen on my personal machine)

Answer (score 1):

My workaround, if you are using tmux:

- detach the tmux session
- close the Terminal app
- start a new Terminal and attach tmux

While still annoying I can at least leave everything running without having to shut down the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Another work around we discovered is go into your settings and turn off software rendering.